# Post e Put com Restangular para api Ruby on Rails

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails

Estou criando uma aplicação *single page* utilizando *angularjs* utilizando uma API *ruby on rails* e o plugin [restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) para efetuar minhas requisições.

### Problema:

A API por padrão espera que as requisições POST e PUT cheguem isolados em uma propriedade com o nome do model, ex:

`user: {name: 'teste', phone: '000000'}, outros_parametros: '';`

Entretanto o *restangular* realiza estas requisições passando os parâmetros soltos, ex:

`name: 'teste', phone: '000000', outros_parametros: '';`

resultando em erro na API: `param is missing or the value is empty: user`

---

#### POST

No POST consegui resolver o problema acredito que não da melhor maneira, colocando o objeto dentro de outro com o nome do model como segue:

**Não Funciona:**

```
$scope.current_user = {name: 'teste', phone: '000000'};
Restangular.all('users').post($scope.current_user);
```

**Funciona:**

```
$scope.current_user = {name: 'teste', phone: '000000'};
Restangular.all('users').post(user: {$scope.current_user});
```

---

#### PUT

No PUT, o *restangular* efetua a requisição com base na instância do objeto da seguinte forma:

```
# GET
$scope.current_user = Restangular.all('users').get(1).$object;
$scope.current_user.name = 'teste2';

# PUT
$scope.current_user.save();
```

e neste caso não consegui contornar o problema.

Se alguém tiver uma solução para o PUT e uma solução melhor para o POST eu agradeço.

Comment: Parece ser um problema específico do Restangular como você pode ver aqui: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/453

Comment: Obrigado, vou ver o que consigo aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução é utilizar um `customPUT`. Veja abaixo como descrevo o acesso a minha API através de uma factory utilizando ES6:

```
const ApiFactory = (Restangular) => {
  'ngInject';

  return Restangular.withConfig((RestangularConfigurer) => {
    RestangularConfigurer.setPlainByDefault(true);
    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl(process.env.API_URL);
  });
};

export default ApiFactory;
```

> `process.env.API_URL` vem da configuração do Webpack, pode ser um valor estático.

Para facilitar o acesso ao resource Rails utilizo `service` do Restangular. Veja abaixo como deve ser a configuração para um resource completo:

```
const DisputeFactory = (Api) => {
  'ngInject';

  let dispute = Api.service('disputes');

  return {
    page: () => dispute.getList(),
    get: (id) => dispute.one(id).get(),
    create: (item) => dispute.post({dispute: item}),
    update: (item) => dispute.customPUT({dispute: item}, item.id),
    delete: (id) => dispute.one(id).remove()
  };
};

export default DisputeFactory;
```

Dessa forma você pode injectar a factory na controller e acessar o recurso de forma simples e fácil.